# Use VS 2010 folder after OS reinstallation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I had to reinstall my OS. Visual Studio 2010 is located on D, so that it survived the new installation of Windows. Can I now use VS2010 "as always" or do I have to setup path variables etc.?

Besides that, which executable do I have to use to start VS? I searched around the executables in the VS folder, but could not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reinstall, as associations (and such other registry entries) will be missing from your new OS.

Fortunately, the VS setup has a **repair** option, so it shouldn't need to copy many files.